# Проблема с запуском программы Python через терминал в sublime text 4

Tags: python, sublime-text

у меня происходит проблема при запуске программы Python через терминал в sublime text. Я перепроверял правильность установленного Python и прочие возможные ошибки.

```
C:\> cd Desktop\python_work
C:\Desktop\python_work> dir hello_world.py
C:\Desktop\python_work> python hello_world.py
```

Вот что я ввожу, и в итоге мне выдает выдает эту ошибку:

```
C:\Users\ilya_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 281ms].
```

Я только недавно начал изучать Python. Пожалуйста, помогите, только на всех вас надежда.
Код который в файле "Hello_world.py": `print("Hello world")`

Comment: А что у вас в `hello_world.py`? Если код небольшой, поместите его полностью в вопрос.

Comment: Там обыкновенный print ("Hello world")

Comment: Странно. Точно там вообще больше ничего нет?

Comment: Да, я все перепробовал и ошибок в написании вроде нет никаких и Python исправно установлен и работает.

Comment: А просто питон запускается? А то может криво установлен.

Comment: Да, с питоном самим все хорошо запускается и так и через консоль windows.

Comment: Юмор в том, что у саблайма нет встроенного терминала, но такой функционал можно добавить через некоторые плагины... в которых видимо и косяк.